# String Comparison in JQuery Needs Explanation

Tags: jquery

I'm having a trouble finding out an explanation with my code..
After echoing back a value from php and received by 'response'
in jquery, I'm trying to compare a String from the value of response..

Not working:

```
success:function(response)
            {
                if (response=='added successfully')
                {
                   alert("");
                }
            },
```

I found a solution over the internet by putting up 'response' inside the $.trim()..And other solution i found out is to put 'exit();'
 after the echoing the value in PHP..

Working

```
success:function(response)
            {
                if ($.trim(response)=='added successfully')
                {
                   alert("");
                }
            },
```

AND

```
    if ($resultset)
    {
        echo 'added successfully';
        exit();
    }
```

Can anyone tell why the first code is not working (hoping for an easy way of explaining it)?

Comment: You probably have some whitespace after the `?>` at the end of the script.

Comment: how to remove or avoid it sir?

Comment: just don't close the php file by removing the last occurrence of `?>`

Answer (score 0):

when you make ajax call say "echofile.php", in response it will give you empty leading and trailing space. in `jsp` it has one page directive to trim the output. `<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>`
or  you can trim response in your jquery success callback function.

To confirm my point you can put alert in your "not working" code. It would definitely have a leading or trailing space.  so you have to trim it on either on client side or on the server side

Answer (score -1):

Most likely you have some spaces after the `?>` at the end of the script. PHP outputs everything outside of `<?php ... ?>` literally. The `exit()` causes the script to stop immediately, so it never gets to the end with the spaces.

Make sure that `<?php` is the very first line of the script. And you don't need `?>` at the end of the script at all. If you don't need to go back into literal HTML mode, just end the script in PHP execution mode.

Comment: "And you don't need ?> at the end of the script at all."                                                                      so i should remove all ?> in php files that return a value to ajax call? but why? still not that clear for me.

Comment: Your editor is probably adding a newline after the last line.